# Sparrow is to bird as snake, human, and lion is to __?

Tags: vocabulary

One can call any flying (or even non-flying) feathered thing a bird (excluding oddities such as bats). But what would we call any animal that stays on the ground? A ground animal?

Note: this isn't a homework question or anything, it's a word I want to use to describe a class, which inherits from `Animal`.

Edit: Clearly this is a very broad question, I believe that I should be more specific. So lets narrow the choices of "ground animals" to those that you could find in a zoo, which means not bugs, dinosaurs, etc.

Comment: There is no such word, because the distinction does not make sense. _Terrestrial animals_ are animals that don't rely on water to live, but live more or less on the ground (so what are penguins, then? Half and half, I guess); but birds are terrestrial as well, just like flies, mosquitoes, bats, etc. are. There is no word for all animals that fly, because they are so diverse; and the same goes for animals that live on the ground. Also, many snakes are amphibians and live partly in water.

Comment: Would a mosquito, fly, butterfly, ladybird/bug be all called *birds*?

Comment: @Mari Those aren't feathered, so they're not included—which is where BitNinja’s parallel already starts to break down.

Comment: Flying feathered things are birds (bats don't have feathers). There's no word for just flying things which would include flying bats, squirrels, snakes, dinosaurs, and insects. Likewise, there's no single word for all terrestrial creatures.

Comment: I suspect all birds (and *only* birds) have feathers - but many of them can't fly anyway, so the air/land distinction isn't central to the category. On the other hand, [sea]water-based "animals" include, for example, ***cod, whale, coral***, and the range of land-based animals is vast. I don't think English is going to have any useful terms for whatever distinction OP is looking for here.

Comment: If you're smart, FumbleFingers has given you a very good expression.

Comment: I feel like this needed to be more specific, I've edited the question.

Comment: The thing is that there are equivalents (eg. mammal, fish etc.) but you've kind of started on a flawed premise by muddling the meaning of the category _bird_. It doesn't fit the category system you're proposing and that's why you can't find others that do. If it suits you, perhaps make up words to mean precisely what you want, such as _hydronian_, _geonian_ and  _aeronian_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about selecting identifiers in a programming language or program.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, [almost all dinosaurs had feathers](https://student.societyforscience.org/article/feathers-what-every-dino-wore), but only avian dinosaurs are flying dinosaurs. Pterosaurs did fly but weren’t dinosaurs and had “protofeathers”, not quite “real” feathers, which developed only in dinosaurs. Well maybe; there is some question out there about whether the feather-like structures are homologous between the pterosaurs (pterodactyls and such) and the theropods (like birds and other dinosaurs). OBTW, penguins fly underwater, you know. 

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You’ve crossed your classes. Although they may lead two lives, and even be among the best-adapted air-breathing marine vertebrates with [one of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelamis_platura) being fully pelagic, but [sea snakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophiidae) are nonetheless still very much part of the [Reptilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptilia) class, and therefore they are by definition not [Amphibians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibian) biologically speaking. All amphibians have a stage with gills; no reptiles do. They must breathe air — or die.

Comment: @tchrist: I know some dinosaurs *had* feathers - I specifically said only birds [now] ***have*** feathers! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No non-dinosaurs have ever had feathers.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm prepared to believe that, though we may find exceptions one day. But all currently-extant dinosaurs are ***birds*** - at least, that's what most people call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cover every animal in the zoo, but, based on the distinction that you have created, I propose using the term **Avian Vertebrate** versus **Non-Avian Vertebrates** - the latter would include the snake, lion and the human.

But [Vertebrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertebrate) wouldn't cover animals like crabs, lobsters etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, in software, is when you make a rigid class hierarchy as you appear to have done, you end up with these problems.  Instead of a rigid hierarchy, you should consider *traits*, one of which is the ability to fly.  Another might be the ability to convert sunlight in to energy.

In reality, the ability to fly doesn't belong to a specific species, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `flying` and `walking`? You can also create classes like `swimming`, etc. These describe what the animals do and are more easily identifiable because of it.

Alternatively, you can describe the location where you see them most active.

- `air`
- `ground`
- `water`
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, 'animal' is one of those *very* misused words... 
this 'tree' may help.. 
https://www.mindmeister.com/50988/animal-kingdom